# BME280 sensor locks ESP8266 and prevents booting

Tags: spi, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an [AZDelivery Node MCU ESP8266](https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/nodemcu) linked via SPI to a [Adafruit BME280 Temperature, Humidity and Pressure Sensor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bme280-humidity-barometric-pressure-temperature-sensor-breakout/overview) that when the data connections are made it prevents the ESP from booting and communicating with the IDE.  The error from Visual Code Studio is:

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz,         
Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 
32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, 
DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory,     
Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Executable segment sizes:
ICACHE : 32768           - flash instruction cache
IROM   : 231724          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR)
IRAM   : 26793   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (IRAM_ATTR, ISRs...)
DATA   : 1496  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP
RODATA : 876   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP
BSS    : 25608 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP

Sketch uses 260889 bytes (27%) of program storage space. Maximum is 958448 bytes.
Global variables use 27980 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53940 bytes for local 
variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM11
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "..packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module> esptool.main(cmdline)

File "..packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 3552, in main
esp.connect(args.before, args.connect_attempts)

File "../packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 529, in
connect raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

I have:

- Tried the board, circuit and code in the Arduino IDE and same error so I do not believe it to be a Visual Code Studio specific problem.
- Tried a different board - same error so I do not believe the board to be faulty.
- Tried a different sensor - same error so I do not believe the sensor to be faulty
- Disconnected the data lines - board boots, sensor shows power and correctly the node reports that the board cannot be found. So this would be the expected behaviour.
- Uploaded the basic block sketch to the ESP and it works correctly.
- Tried circuit and sensor with an Arduino Uno and it works.

The code is taken from the [BME280test](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BME280_Library/blob/master/examples/bme280test/bme280test.ino) example with appropriate changes made to the pin numbers and line 31 commented out to disable i2c with either 31/32 uncommented to enable SPI. Below is the circuit I am using with the following pinout:

- 3v3/Vin  N/A Red Vin
- GND  N/A Black   GND
- D5   HSPI SCK    White   SCK  (GPIO 14)
- D6   HSPI MISO   Green   SDO  (GPIO 12)
- D7   HSPI MOSI   Blue    SDI  (GPIO 13)
- D8   HSPI CS Yellow  CS (GPIO 15)

[image: This is the circuit.].

So, it seems to be an error with the ESP8266 and BME280 that blocks any sort of communication with    the board but I have nothing to go on.  I'm going to try a ESP32 and see if it gives a different response.  If anyone has any idea or has experienced something similar I would welcome some insights.

Edit: The ESP32 (same brand) arrived this afternoon and works with same code. I should have also said that I've got an SD Card working over SPI on the ESP8266.

Comment: I would try with a pull up resistor at /CS. You feed Vin of the sensor with 3.3 V, I doubt it can create local 3.3V with that. What about feeding 3V input as well?

Comment: Try another pin as CS than GPIO15. In SPI master mode, you can use any pin for CS.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I believe I did try it on the Vin but would need to repeat the test and trying an alternate CS is a good idea.   I'm working on a ESP32 now and to be honest this is a better platform for me.   I'll try and visit this shortly for the sake of anyone else with same issue.  Thanks again.